# VHDL enumeration with specific bit length

Tags: enums, vhdl

I have a number of constants. Each of the constants have a length of 8 bits.

I want to change it to an enumeration, for two reasons.
1. The value for each constant does not matter, It just have to be different values.
2. Since the values for each item does not matter, I want to use the enumeration, to not care about giving the constants numbers.

I know you can do something like this:

```
type fruit is (banana, apple, orange);
attribute enum_encoding : string;
attribute enum_encoding of fruit : type is "00000000 00000001 00000010";
```

However that seems like double work, since I, after all have to give the items nubmers. I just want to specify, that it has to be 8 bits, and let Vivado do the counting.

Comment: If the values for each item do not matter, why are you trying to force a particular encoding?

Comment: I dont think I was all clear. The values has to be 8 bits. But starting from 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: Why do they have to be 8 bits? Perhaps it would help if you showed where you use the enumerated values.

Comment: I am implementing a von neumann architecture in vhdl as a school assignment. The control store has a 8 bit address input and output. At the same time, I also read 8 bit at a time from the ROM. So it has to be 8 bit

Answer (score 0):

As I understant you read "0000_0010" from your ROM, which equals 2, which means you want to select "orange". You can use the VHDL predefined attribute `'VAL`.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_e is end entity test_e;

architecture test_a of test_e is
    type fruit is (banana, apple, orange);
    constant rom_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000010";
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    constant sel_fr : fruit := fruit'val(to_integer(unsigned(rom_out)));
begin
end architecture;
```

`sel_fr` will be "orange".